# Как именно «доктора» вытеснили «докторы»?

Tags: орфография, множественное-число

Yandex.Zen:

> В современном русском языке есть примерно 300 слов, у которых именительный падеж множественного числа, так скажем, вариативен. Окончания на -ы (-и) — более привычны для нас и считаются литературными (редакторы, корректоры, тренеры). Но с годами формы на -а (-я) сумели полноправно занять место некоторых литературных вариантов. Если на рубеже XIX–XX веков были «докторы», то сейчас единственно верный вариант «доктора» с ударением на последнюю букву.

Вопрос: как именно, когда точно и при каких обстоятельствах формы на -а вытеснили (для некот. слов) формы на -ы?

Answer (score 2):

**Дополнение от 08.01.2021.**
Мне удалось найти [единый источник](http://rjano.ruslang.ru/ru/archive/2018-1/9-32), в котором А.А. Зализняк сделал детальный обзор всей известной на сегодняшний день (2018 г.) информации по вопросу "каким образом?". В частности, подробно рассмотрено дв.ч. таких слов, как *р**о**га, б**о**ка*, для которых удалось установить, что ударение в дв.ч. падало на первый слог, а не на последний, как в нынешнем мн.ч. Это послужило толчком к развитию теории. Я вынес этот источник в начало ответа ввиду его особой ценности и авторитетности.

---

---

> Вопрос: как именно, когда точно и при каких обстоятельствах формы на
> -а вытеснили (для некот. слов) формы на -ы?

Проще всего ответить на вопрос "когда точно?"
**Ответ**. Для каждого слова по-разному. При этом некоторые слова переходят из одной нормы в другую, а потом возвращаются обратно (например, **волосы** в XVIII в., **волоса** в начале XX в., и сейчас снова **волосы**). *Докторы* перешли в *доктора* в точности в период со второй половины XVIII в. (ещё М.В. Ломоносов почти всегда писал *докторы*) по вторую половину XIX в. (по утверждению К. Чуковского).

Со временем изменяется также точка зрения языковедов на эти вопросы. 100 лет тому В.И. Чернышев писал, что за редкими исключениями мы наблюдаем полное господство форм на **-а** (хотя и отмечает, что ещё в начале XVIII в. *дома, рога, паруса, снега* и т.п. казались вульгарными и малограмотными). Но прошло ещё каких-то 50 лет и мнение профессионалов изменилось на диаметрально противоположное:

> ...Формы на **-а** имеют обычно разговорную или профессиональную окраску (ср. *пекаря, карбаса, клевера, кожуха, шкипера, промысла* и под.). Формы же на **-и(-ы)** более нейтральны и для большинства слов отвечают традиционным нормам литературного языка: *пекари, цехи, слесари, промыслы, секторы, прожекторы* и т. д.

Истина, как водится, где-то посредине.

Что касается вопросов *как именно?* и *при каких обстоятельствах?*, то эти вопросы чрезвычайно интересны, но ответы на них были бы слишком громоздкими для формата rus.SE. Поэтому я бы посоветовал просто погуглить эти ответы (я обычно ищу в гуглокнигах, а потом скачиваю нужные книги на Либгене). Хочу только обратить внимание, что обсуждаемая флексия тесно связана с изменением акцентной парадигмы и, возможно, является её следствием. Про изменения акцентной парадигмы лучше гуглить лекции А.Зализняка.

**Ответ** behemothus'у.

Со второй половины XVIII в. у многих уже начинают появляться *доктора*, не только у Ломоносова. Вы не видели, сколько вхождений в Нацкорпус имеют *докторы* у Ломоносова против единственного *доктора*? Если не видели, то мне это очень странно, а если видели, то ещё более странно.

В документах времён Алексея Михайловича встречается только "роги". Из пословиц: *были роги, да посломали боги*. В некоторых диалектах сохраняются "роги".
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

По поводу *пекаря* (если это его Вы называете *лекарем*), можете сами посмотреть, как изменялись нормы в словарях уже при нашей жизни.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117778/discussion-on-answer-by-grizzly-----).

Answer (score 0):

> Вопрос: как именно, когда точно и при каких обстоятельствах формы на
> -а вытеснили (для некот. слов) формы на -ы?

Насчет "как именно" и "при каких обстоятельствах" - это вам к следователю надо, простите, чтоб такие вопросы задавать. Язык меняется не одномоментно и не по чьей-то воле.
"Когда" - это еще более или менее корректный вопрос, но ваш источник и тут ошибается. Гораздо раньше, чем на рубеже веков. Но и тут могу дать лишь некую статистику.

> ― Я, голубчик, все бросаю… Мне ***доктора*** запретили пить. Пью теперь
> только потому, что сразу нездорово бросать… [А. П. Чехов. Драма на
> охоте (1884)]  ←…

> ― Да мне холодно… я покрыться хочу… ― Не велено халатами покрываться:
> ***доктора*** запрещают. Это не порядок, на это одеяло есть… [В. В.
> Крестовский. Петербургские трущобы. Книга о сытых и голодных. Ч. 5
> (1867)]  ←…→

> Никто ему не верил, а все считали помешанным, хоть господа ***доктора*** и
> дали свидетельство, что он в полном и здравом уме. [В. И. Даль. Хмель,
> сон и явь (1843)]  ←…→

> Минская улыбнулась. ― Призовите доктора, ― сказала она. ― ***Доктора*** не
> помогут ― это сплин! ― Влюбитесь! [М. Ю. Лермонтов. Штосс (1841)]
> ←…→

> ***Доктора*** танбовские четверо всякой день приезжали и наконец положили,
> что у меня каменная болезнь, чтоб ехать в Москву. [М. П. Загряжский.
> Записки (1770-1811)] ←…→

> Сего недостатка ничем не можно скорее наполнить, как для изучения
> докторства послать довольное число российских студентов в иностранные
> университеты и учрежденным и впредь учреждаемым внутри государства
> университетам дать, между прочими привилегиями, власть производить
> достойных ***в доктора***. [М. В. Ломоносов. [О размножении и сохранении
> российского народа]  ←…→

(из Нацкорпуса).

Последние цитаты по времени вполне совпадают с первыми фиксациями слова "доктор" в русском языке. Тут впору всерьез задуматься, а было ли вообще когда-то "докторы" нормативным.

Впрочем, в нацкорпусе действительно есть и десятка три вхождений "докторы", погоды они не делают.
Штук двадцать - в текстах не позже середины XVIII века, остальные - в сочетаниях с именем собственным типа "[этакие] докторы Ватсоны", в том числе и в относительно современных источниках. Последняя форма итересна сама по себе, похоже, что она-то вполне нормативна, но это отдельный вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Вынужден дать свой ответ и на вопрос, ответ на который выдал  grizzly.

Скажу сразу, я не предполагал, что автор спрашивает о том, когда вообще появилась тенденция к образованию форм множественного м.р. на -А/-Я или когда они стали вытеснять формы на -Ы/-И.

Я полагал, что вопрос связан с единственной формой дорторы-доктора и не предполагает каких-то обобщений.

Для связности повторю, что причины такого перехода конкретного слова очень темны (grizzly вообще эту часть вопроса опускает), а время начала перехода я отношу не к XVIII веку (что можно бы вывести из странной неаттрибутированной цитаты с упоминанием Греча), а гораздо раньше. Слава Богу, мой оппонент согласился, что уже во времена Ломоносова, то есть в период самого появления слова в русском), это слова имело вариативную форму множественного.

Теперь об обобщении.
**Когда и почему появились такие формы в русском.**

На самом деле есть две "причины" появления таких форм в русском и, соответственно, две группы слов.
Первая - архаизм, влияние форм совершенно забытого "двойственного числа". К этой группе смело можно отнести все парные предметы - глаза, рога, рукава, берега...
Двойственное число в древнерусском существовало у всех существительных, для большинства слов мужского рода эта форма имела окончание -а/-я. Таким образом можно утверждать, что это форма была всегда, вопрос причине её возникновения теряет смысл, интересно только то, когда именно эта форма потеснила настоящее множественное ("роги" и некоторые другие).

Вот давайте на примере этих "рогов" и разберемся. Начнем с того, что единичные вхождения "роги" встречаются до 30-х годов XIX века, да и то все больше - как архаизм. Позднее - уже четко: либо тоже как архаизм, либо стилизация.

Начиная с 1800 года появляется рога:

> В его святилище хранились серебряные и золотые чаши (из коих при
> торжественных случаях люди знатнейшие пили и ели), также рога
> буйволовы, оправленные золотом: они служили и стаканами и трубами. [Н.
> М. Карамзин. История государства Российского: Том 1 (1803-1818)]

Думаю не будет большой ошибкой, что на всем протяжении истории современного русского языка эта форма существовала всегда и к середине XIX века полностью вытеснила недолго существовавший вариант "роги". Недолго - потому, что сама эта форма появилась из исторического "рози" (об этой форме - см. "первая палатализация"). К сожалению, неоднозначность значения слово "роги" в древнерусском (оно могло означать и розы" и некий символ могущества - https://efremova.slovaronline.com/94715-ROG), не дает возможности точно разобраться ни во времени перехода рози-роги, ни в его причинах.

Зато в остальных случаях - берега, глаза, рукава - все предельно ясно. Эта форма двойственного числа и она никогда после исчезновения двойственного не испытывала конкуренции со стороны собственно множественного. Было бы крайне неверно оперировать такими словами как аргументом для установления времени возникновения форм типа "директора" (историческое - директоры) или учителя (учители).

В отношении причин для такого перехода последних (доктора, учителя, трактора, якоря) тоже нет никакой ясности.
Очевидно только, что такому изменению подвержены слова, оканчивающиеся на -р/-рь (в единичных случаях - на -ль) с предшествующим безударным гласным.  Последнее  особенно важно, например "шофера" ненормативно уже потому, что может быть образовано только от формы "ш**о**фер", но никак не нормативного "шоф**ё**р". Почему именно эти слова оказались подвержены такому переходу - сказать совершенно невозможно. Более того, совершенно невозможно установить, почему *лекаря, якоря, егеря, лагеря* подпали под действие этого процесса, а *пекари и слесари/ - нет.
**Остается только констатировать, что ни о времени, ни о причинах такого перехода мы не можем сказать ничего определенного.**
Судя по всему, "доктора" оказалось одним из первых слов, испытавших на себе его влияние. Видимо, с самого появления этого слова в русском.

И повторю самое главное в контексте разговора с grizzly. ***Описанные два процесса (рукава, берега, рога и доктора, лекаря, учителя) - это два совершенно разных явления в русском языке. Не надо их смешивать ни при каких обстоятельствах***.

(+)===

Форма "дом**а**" (века, рода и единичные другие) полностью выпадает из обеих групп. Ничего о ней путного сказать не могу. Да, это новая форма, но чем она мотивирована - загадка пока не разрешенная. Возможно сказалось подсознательное стремление избежать омонимии/омографии (века-веки, рода-роды, дом**а**-д**о**ма), но ведь есть же еще и года/годы, правда в этом случая императивности форм "года" нет.

Comment: Мои утверждения Вы не поняли, рекомендованную мной литературу не посмотрели, про грамматику Ададурова вряд ли слышали. В "Русском именном словоизменении" А.А. Зализняка можете, кроме **шофёра**, найти такие слова: *варвары, менторы, рыцари, гангстеры, канцлеры, квакеры, бюргеры, фермеры, преторы, спикеры, лидеры* и т.п. Имхо, он чуть аккуратнее Вас производит деление групп и объясняет закономерности. Как я уже объяснял ранее, добротный ответ на эти вопросы слишком объёмен, а профанировать такую сложную тему я не захотел.

Comment: @grizzly я очень терпеливый человек в вопросах культуры общения, но после того, как вы соообщили, что у вас-де нет времени со мной общаться, считаю ваши распальцовки неуместными. Давайте уже по существу.

Comment: *В "Русском именном словоизменении" А.А. Зализняка можете, кроме шофёра, найти такие слова* - Судя по всему, вы не удосужились даже прочитать мой текст. Я говорил о группах слов, которые **приобрели или имели окончание -а во множественном**.  У Зализняка это вообще одна группа, возможно с подгруппами, сейчас лень разбираться. Но никакие блогеры с рыцарями там даже рядом не лежали. *Ш**о**фер* упомянут мной совсем не в связи с ними.

Comment: Заметьте, я стараюсь содержательно отвечать на ваши замечания по своему ответу, И не в пример вам не посылаю далеко и надолго искать удобную вам литературу по белу свету.

Answer (score 0):

Ответ grizzly

В последней версии своего ответа grizzly ссылается на работу Зализняка, саму по себе безусловно ценную и интересную. Но, как легко убедиться, ответа на поставленный вопрос в ней нет, по крайней мере grizzly его не нашел, послав желающих в гугл. Типа "Разбирайся мол сама". Понятно, что такое отношение к читающему выходит за рамки даже не научной корректности, а элементарной вежливости.

А между тем в статье Зализняка есть кое-что вполне пригодное стать основой для ответа.

> Что касается слов а.п. а , то они могли включиться в изучаемый нами
> процесс, только если уже изменили акцентовку. Такое изменение не было
> произвольным — слово могло лишь уподобиться одной из двух других а.п.
> При неодносложной основе уподобиться а.п. смогли только слова с
> начальным ударением в ед. числе (например , пáрусъ , пáруса ) —
> в соответствии с господствующей акцентной моделью в исконной а.п.
> Вначале акцентная эволюция таких слов а.п. а была двухэтапной.
> Например, для слова пáрусъ: 1) пáрусы, пáрусам менялось на пáрусы,
> парусáм (по модели волосы, волосáм); 2) пáрусы,
> парусáм менялось на парусá, парусáм (как городá, городáм).
> ***Позднее, в эпоху активной экспансии модели И. мн. на á эта эволюция
> упростилась; скажем, бýферы, бýферам могло уже непосредственно
> заменяться на буферá, буферáм***. Далее на базе таких слов
> сформировалась четкая акцентная модель с именно таким ударением для
> двусложных слов на безударные -ор, -ер, -ель (например, трáктор,
> скýтер , штемпель). И совсем поздно эта модель захватила уже и
> некоторые слова со срединным ударением, а именно из числа тех, у
> которых последние два слога основы удовлетворяли тому же условию
> (например, профессор, директор, учитель).

http://rjano.ruslang.ru/ru/archive/2018-1/9-32
(Курсив мой, Ударение в ряде примеров, имеющееся в источнике в цитате отсутствует по техническим причинам - b-s).

Зализняк совершенно обоснованно выделяет группу двусложных слов с безударным конечным -ор, -ер и дает ей место на исторической шкале. Вот, собственно, и всё. Ничего гуглить не надо. Надо только посмотреть общую картину начавшегося перехода таких слов... Легко даже по нацкорпусу видеть, что речь идет примерно о середине XIX столетия. Никак не раньше, само слово "буфер" (как, впрочем, и доктор) сравнительно молодое.

> В частности, подробно рассмотрено дв.ч. таких слов, как рога, бока,
> для которых удалось установить, что ударение в дв.ч. падало на первый
> слог, а не на последний, как в нынешнем мн.ч. Это послужило толчком к
> развитию теории. Я вынес этот источник в начало ответа ввиду его
> особой ценности и авторитетности.

Из этого факта (да, интересного) ровно ничего не следует. Зализняк впоминает его лишь в связи с тем, что "рога" с ударением на флексию не могло быть прямым наследством древнерусского двойственного.